# "In which ocean are The Bahamas?" or "In which ocean are The Bahamas located?"

Tags: grammar, american-english, pronouns, questions

Which is more grammatically correct:

"In which ocean are The Bahamas?"

or

"In which ocean are The Bahamas located?"

Also "Where are the _____?" vs "Where are the _____ located?" same question. Thank you!

Comment: Strictly, the answer must be 'the Atlantic ocean', since the Caribbean is a sea within the Atlantic (just in case you didn't know that).

Answer (score 2):

*Located* is completely unnecessary in your questions.

Not ungrammatical, not an inappropriate word; but it's cumbersome, and suggests that you're desperately trying to make yourself sound important.

The most natural form of the question is *Which ocean are the Bahamas in?*

Answer (score -1):

You have the right idea. Technically, you're never supposed to end a sentence with a preposition (i.e. to, from, in, etc.) and most of the time, personally, the way to avoid it would be either one of the sentences you provided.

I realize that isn't exactly the answer you're looking for ... you're more focused on the best way to structure that question. In which case, in my opinion, I'd go with:

"In which Ocean are the Bahamas located?"

Comment: First, not one of the OP's examples ends with a preposition, so this answer has no relation to the question. Secondly, please don't promulgate that bogus rule. Prepositions are perfectly good things to end a sentence with, and always have been.